# How to get context in getView of adapter for listview

Tags: android, listview, fonts, layout-inflater, typeface

I have three questions:

1. I am using getApplicationContext unlike all the examples I have seen which just say context. How do I get the context here? Or is the application context fine?
2. Is there any performance penalty for me overriding the getView instead of letting it handle it by itself (I am only doing it to set a custom font)
3. Is there anything I should be aware of while using this approach (as I am just copy and pasting without understanding what it will do if I have 250 items in my list). Any potential leaks I can cause?

My Code:

```
private Typeface arabicFont;
arabicFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arabicfont.ttf");

...

_arabicAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                          R.layout.book_list_item_arabic,
                                          _cursor,
                                          new String[] {"NumberArabic", "Arabic"},
                                          new int[] {R.id.txtNumber, R.id.txtBookName},
                                          CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_list_item_arabic, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtBookName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);
        txtBookName.setTypeface(arabicFont);

        txtBookName.setText("\"العربية\"");
        return convertView;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

ViweGroup parent is certainly not null，so, parent.getContext() maybe the best way for fetch context

Answer (score 0):

> I am using getApplicationContext unlike all the examples I have seen which just say context. How do I get the context here? Or is the application context fine?

You are passing `this` to your constructor here

```
_arabicAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.book_list_item_arabic,
                                      _cursor,
                                      new String[] {"NumberArabic", "Arabic"},
                                      new int[] {R.id.txtNumber, R.id.txtBookName},
                                      CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION)
```

which would be your `Context` so you should have a variable in your `Adapter` that is of type `Context` which you assign in your constructor.

> Is there any performance penalty for me overriding the getView instead of letting it handle it by itself (I am only doing it to set a custom font)

Not that I'm aware of but if it is just a font then you could assign this in a `style` for the `TextView` that you use for your `ListView` items.

> Is there anything I should be aware of while using this approach (as I am just copy and pasting without understanding what it will do if I have 250 items in my list). Any potential leaks I can cause?

Yes, you should be aware that copy/paste code without understanding it is always trouble. Go through line by line and make sure you understand what everything is doing.

Comment: The Context does not seem to support getSystemService() for some reason. Says cannot be referenced statically

Comment: How are you doing it? Did you create some variable, say, `Context c;` then assign it to the context you passed in constructor then do, `c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`?